# Сервис и компонент конвейера обработчика запросов, то есть компонент middlewire, - это одно и то же? Если нет, то поясните, пожалуйста, разницу

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Сервис и компонент конвейера-обработчика запросов, то есть компонент middlewire, - это одно и то же? Если нет, то поясните, пожалуйста, разницу.

Comment: что документация об этом говорит?

Answer (score 0):

Дам вырезку из [статьи](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/2.18.php)

Как правило, для обработки запроса применяется не один, а несколько компонентов middleware. И в этом случае большую роль может играть порядок их помещения в конвейер обработки запроса, а также то, как они взаимодействуют с другими компонентами.

Кроме того, каждый компонент middleware может обрабатывать запрос до и после последующих в конвейере компонентов. Данное обстоятельство позволяет предыдущим компонентам корректировать результат обработки последующих компонентов.

Так вот сервис это само приложение, а конвейер обработки запроса это часть его которая отвечает за обработку запроса.